# Can "fish" really be spelled "pheti"?

Tags: spelling, spoken-english

My teacher has a sign in his room that says:

> The English Language is a Challenge: This is why "Fish" can be spelled "Pheti"!

Is this true or is just to confuse students?

Comment: It's a very old joke, mocking the irregularity of English spelling. The version I know spells *fish* as **{ghoti}**: {gh} as in {enough}, {o} as in {women} and {ti} as in {nation}. Another version says {ghoti} is pronounced // (that is, entirely silent): {gh} as in {through}, {o} as in {people}, {t} as in {ballet} and {i} as in {business}.

Comment: @StoneyB Ha! I'd heard fish = ghoti but not the 'silent ghoti' version. That's hilarious. Also, that looks like the answer to me. :)

Comment: I think this is Off Topic General Reference. I'm sure OP doesn't really believe the average Anglophone would recognise the word *pheti* as simply another way of spelling *fish*. And if he doubts, let him look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: If you see it on a teacher's wall, why wouldn't you want to know why?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/47590/16833

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StoneyB is absolutely correct in that ***Pheti*** is a joke, a play on the idiosyncrasies of the English spelling and pronunciation but it doesn't end there. In fact, it should arouse a phonic and phonemic awareness in the reader or student reading that word. As it appears to have done so with you.

In order to pronounce this word as "fish" **/fɪʃ/**, you need be familiar with some of the so-called [conventional spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inventive_spelling#Instruction_for_Conventional_Spelling)  guidelines.

- ***ph*** is often pronounced as /f/. For example; **ph**otos;  **ph**otocopier; ele**ph**ant /ˈelɪ**f**ənt/.
- ***e*** is sometimes pronounced as /ɪ/. For example; **E**ngland, wom**e**n /ˈwɪm**ɪ**n/. N.B. See how the letter o is pronounced in the same way!
- **ti** is sometimes pronounced as /ʃ/. For example; infla**ti**on /ɪnˈfleɪ**ʃ**ən/;  sta**ti**on /ˈsteɪ**ʃ**ən/.

Note that in all the examples I said "is *sometimes* pronounced" because as nearly everyone knows by now, there are no fixed rules in English spelling or pronunciation.

Comment: Although, this means that *pheti* can be pronounced *fish*. I don't see how it means *fish* can be spelled *pheti*, as spelling rules and pronunciation are something different. I know, it's supposed to be a joke.

Comment: I should have clarified, and confirmed that it is highly unlikely that anyone will propose that pheti is the speling for "fish". Although, now come to think of it [**phish**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/phish) could be seen as an alternative spelling... :)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is a joke nowadays, it’s because before Dr Johnson wrote the dictionary, there wasn’t any correct way of spelling something as there weren’t any rules to our spelling, hence why our phonetics don’t tend to make much sense. For example if you look through Shakespeare’s original scripts you’ll find that he spells his own name in different ways as well as words. So whilst ‘ghoti’ and ‘pheti’ are jokes, in a time before the dictionary was established, these two spellings would be accepted as one of the numerous spellings for fish.